# How to avoid getting invalid argument when controlling joystick with smbus library

Tags: python, smbus

I am trying to control a 5 pin joystick with raspberry pi
the code is attached
however when I run this I get an error
does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

I expected it to show me the position of the joystick when pushed
i tried checking for typos and things that didn't make sense
nothing worked

```
from signal import signal, SIGTERM, SIGHUP, pause
from smbus import SMBus
from time import sleep
from math import log10

bus = SMBus(1)
ads7830_commands = (0x84, 0xc4, 0x94, 0xd4, 0xa4, 0xe4, 0xb4, 0xf4)

def safe_exit(signum, frame):
    exit(1)

def read_ads7830(input):
    bus.write_byte(0xb4, ads7830_commands[input])
    return bus.read_byte(0x4b)


signal(SIGTERM, safe_exit)
signal(SIGHUP, safe_exit)

try:
    while True:
        print(f"x: {read_ads7830(7)}, Y: {read_ads7830(6)}")

        sleep(0.1)
    pause()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Comment: sorry please ignore the second iteration of the code only read up to the first Keyboard Interrupt command

Comment: you could edit code and remove second iteration